# ¿Como Reversar un string que ya fue reversado usando pilas?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

He reversado un string utilizando pilas , pero no se que debo hacer para reversarlo nuevamente.
He tratado de hacerlo copiando el string con strcpy para utilizar el metodo nuevamente y reverse el string a su estado original , pero no me es permitido ya que no copia nada.

Debe hacer esto:
Ex.

Console Input: Hello World!

reversado: !dlroW olleH

reversado Nuevamente: Hello World!

Espero puedan ayudarme indicandome que puedo hacer o si me pudiesen corregir donde tenga algun error.

Gracias.

```cpp
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PTR {
    char character;
    PTR* Next;

   public:
    PTR(char, PTR*);
    ~PTR() {}

    friend class Stack;
};

class Stack {
    PTR* Top;

   public:
    Stack() { Top = NULL; }
    ~Stack();
    void Push(char);
    char Pop();
};

PTR::PTR(char c = '\0', PTR* n = NULL) {
    character = c;
    Next = n;
}

void Stack::Push(char c) { Top = new PTR(c, Top); }

char Stack::Pop() {
    PTR* aux;
    char temporal;
    if (Top == NULL) return '\0';
    aux = Top;
    temporal = aux->character;
    Top = Top->Next;
    delete aux;
    return temporal;
}

Stack::~Stack() {
    while (Top) Pop();
}

int main() {
    Stack A;
    char x;
    cout << "Write a Message= ";
    x = getch();
    while (x != 13) {
        A.Push(x);
        cout << "*";
        x = getch();
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        cout << ".";
        Sleep(500);
    }
    cout << endl;
    do {
        x = A.Pop();
        cout << x;
    } while (x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> He tratado de hacerlo copiando el string con strcpy para utilizar el metodo nuevamente

El asunto es que no le estas guardando en un string, estas almacenando cada caracter en un objeto propio, podrías probar volviendolos a guardar en otra pila:

```
Stack B;
...
do {
        x = A.Pop();
        cout << x;
        B.Push(x);
    } while (x);

//Reinvirtiendo
do {
        x = B.Pop();
        cout << x;
    } while (x);
```

Aquí irias ingresando cada caracter `x` en un segundo `Stack` llamado `B` a medida de que vayas sacando cada elemento de `A`, luego repites el mismo proceso que hiciste para mostrar el array reversado.